# Vanilla Javascript beginner

Tags: javascript

**I'm learning javascript a week .
I have a problem which is difficult to understand.**

```
function power(exponent) {
  for(var i = 0; i < exponent; i++) {
    exponent -= 1;
  }
  return exponent;
}

document.write(power(3));
// result : 1
```

**when I pass return exponent inside for loop below (result : 2)**

```
function power(exponent) {
  for(var i = 0; i < exponent; i++) {
    exponent -= 1;
    return exponent;
  }
}

document.write(power(3));
// result : 2
```

**Why with two case which result is not equal to 0 . I think for loop will loop three (exponent - 1) and result will equal to 0.**

**Please explain for me ?**

**Thanks**

Comment: because you return on the first iteration. console.log() is your friend with the debugger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function is returning after one loop as you've got the `return` keyword in the loop. A function can only return once, so as soon as it hits `return`, it returns the value and leaves the function. If you move `return` outside of the loop, the function will only exit after the loop has been completed.

Additionally, by reducing the `exponent` variable every time, you're reducing the amount of iterations of the loop (after one iteration, you reduce it to two so it will only loop twice, etc). For it to go to zero, you need to copy the value of `exponent` into a looping variable (such as `n`) so it remains constant and the code loops `exponent` times.

```
var n = exponent;

for(var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  exponent -= 1;
}
return exponent;
```

Comment: Thanks you very much . I just learned by myself so I wasn't sure about background knowledge . I need to how to learn to meet many problems like this . Because I become a front-end developer like you . You can point way best ?